# USB-C HUB UGREEN 9-1 not working (works on Windows)

Tags: hdmi, 21.04, thunderbolt, usb-c

The hardware:

- [Customized Intel Whitebook](https://www.newegg.com/p/2WC-003C-00040)
- [USB-C HUB UGREEN CM212](https://es.aliexpress.com/item/32821301992.html)

The laptop has a Thunderbolt 3 USB-c port. The hub works really well in Windows 10, the HDMI transmits the image at 144 Hz. However, when I switch to Linux it doesn't work. I have been using it on another laptop with USB-c but without a Thunderbolt port, and it works well but without HDMI transmission enable.

I tried with ubuntu 20.04 but without any success.

I have thought that the problem is with the Linux drivers but I can't get any success searching for help on google.

`lspci -d ::0c03 -k`

```
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 10)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci
01:00.2 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU106 USB 3.1 Host Controller (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Daewoo Telecom Ltd TU106 USB 3.1 Host Controller
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci
3a:00.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 USB Controller [Titan Ridge 2C 2018] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 USB Controller [Titan Ridge 2C 2018]
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci
```

lsusb

```
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 174c:1153 ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1153 SATA 3Gb/s bridge
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:0316 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Card Reader
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 048d:ce00 Integrated Technology Express, Inc. ITE Device(8291)
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 8087:0029 Intel Corp. AX200 Bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04f2:b68b Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd HD Webcam
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: What is the full output of `lsusb` when the hub is connected?

Comment: Hi @Joag. wich dirver did you install on linux?

Comment: @matigo I updated the response. I have another hub connected to the computer on the usb3

Comment: @jpbrain I don't install any particular driver. I just only install the Ubuntu 21.04 as I did with my old laptop.

Comment: You don't notice any change while un/plugging on `watch -d lsusb`? Same but looking on `journalctl -xf`?

Comment: According to the description chips are not listed in your post. Chips are  VIA VL102 & VL817, Parade PS176HDM, AX88179 . can you look for references using #dmesg?

Comment: @PabloBianchi The results from `watch -d lsusb` is  `pcieport 0000:00:1b.0: PME: Spurious native interrupt! usb usb6-port1: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?`. The usb c worked for a few minutes and after a while appeared disconnect from the computer in ubuntu.

Comment: Using `sudo dmesg | grep -e usb -e xhci -e hub` appeared the following: `[    1.462443] usb usb6: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003, bcdDevice= 5.11
[    1.462445] usb usb6: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.462446] usb usb6: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.462447] usb usb6: Manufacturer: Linux 5.11.0-22-generic xhci-hcd
[    1.462449] usb usb6: SerialNumber: 0000:3a:00.0
[    1.462616] hub 6-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.462630] hub 6-0:1.0: 2 ports detected`

Comment: It appears that at the beginning the hub is recognized but after a while, it is disconnected. The problem is that in windows it does not occurs